# Flask Application Alternative File Structure (app.py, templates folder)

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a simple flask application where the **file structure** is

- project/

  - app.py
  - templates/
  - static/

    - css/

      - style.css
    - js/

      - code.js

With this structure the below code works completely fine.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return(render_template('html/index.html'))
if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But I want to keep all my python code (in this case **app.py**) to be inside a package called **server/** and then if required create some sub-packages inside that package (**server/**).

With that, the project file structure would be like below

- project/

  - server

    - app.py
  - templates/
  - static/

    - css/

      - style.css
    - js/

      - code.js

But with this file structure I want to know what the routing path needs to be, so that I can link my html file in the **template/html** folder.

```py
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return(render_template('html/index.html'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a relative or an absolute path when initializing the `Flask` object:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates")
```